# Make Assetic output conventional links

Tags: symfony, assetic

Is it possible to mimic "normal" assets using Assetic so that the following:

```
{% javascripts '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
  <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Would become,

```
<script src="bundles/App/js/1.js"></script>
<script src="bundles/App/js/2.js"></script>
```

-- if it is a given that `1.js` and `2.js` are in `'@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/*'`

The latter, instead of what it becomes currently in Assetic's debug mode:

```
<script src="/dev.php/js/w/aaaaa_1.js"></script>
<script src="/dev.php/js/w/aaaaa_2.js"></script>
```

Basically, in development, I want to be able to retrieve the assets directly from the webserver, **without** using,

1. Symfony's controller to serve the content (as it adds 1-2s per asset -- even for small files)
2. the `$ php bin/console assetic:watch` (as it uses a lot of CPU on our shared development server)
3. Manually dump after each asset change.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do this:

```
{% javascripts 'bundles/app/js/*' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

And use the command `assets:install --symlink`

in the config_dev.yml

```
assetic:
    use_controller: false
```

However using the @ notation resolves caching issues when you deploy since the name will be different when the content changes causing browsers to be forced to download the new file.

More information in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html).

Comment: I have tried using the `'@'` and the `'bundles/...'` reference to the asset, both result in `dev.php` src links, e.g.,  `"/dev.php/js/w/aaaaa_1.js"`. This uses Symfony/PHP to deliver the file and adds considerable stalls during transfer of the file to the user (see point .1 in the Question).

Comment: The config_dev.yml should hold use_controller: false as well. (previously wrong in my comment)